# Using AuthInterceptor in a Phonegap application

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I´m creating a Phonegap Application with angular js and Ionic framework. This application uses http requests to a server and i need to inject some parameters in each http request. For this topic i´m trying to use a service called authInterceptor (which i have used before in a web application and works perfectly) that have to intercept all http requests but this service is not working in the mobile. I´m not sure if i have to do something different in a phonegap application. This is my service:

```
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken) {

var interceptorFactory = {};
// this will happen on all HTTP requests
interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {

    if (condition) 
        //inject the parameters

    return config;
};

// happens on response errors
interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response) {

    // if our server returns a 403 forbidden response
    if (response.status == 403){

    }
    // return the errors from the server as a promise
    return $q.reject(response);
};

return interceptorFactory;
```

});

I hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: If it works in a webapp it should work on mobile as long as you have taken care of CORS headers. How did you test it? In a browser, in an emulator or in real device?